# PHP/PDO - EXPLAIN SELECT for PDO is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

this is my query:

```
    $query = $db->prepare("

            EXPLAIN SELECT transaction.id, transaction.dateCreated, transaction.dateUpdated, transaction.brandId, transaction.clientId, transaction.serviceId, transaction.currencyCode, transaction.type, transaction.token, transaction.amount, transaction.reason, transaction.referenceOrderId, transaction.serviceTransactionId, transaction.chainMode, transaction.bonusCode, transaction.codeId, transaction.codeMessage, su.name AS user_name, su.surname AS user_surname, b.name AS brand_name, su.email_address, su.player_id, sandbox, integrationId 
            FROM transaction_AstroPay transaction
            LEFT JOIN tokens t ON transaction.token = t.token
            LEFT JOIN sys_users su ON su.id=t.user_id
            LEFT JOIN brands b ON b.api_brand_code = transaction.brandId
            WHERE transaction.clientId = :clientId


    ");
    $query->bindParam(':clientId',$clientId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();  
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The query is performed well and the data is fetched from the DB.
My question is how can I get detailed information about how much time it took. In `mysqli` the `EXPLAIN SELECT` was working.

We took the information in `mysqli` like this:

```
$sql = 'EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition = "condition"';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
echo $row[0];
```

How can i do it here in PDO ?

Comment: — Does your comment mean "The problem was caused by a typo and I have now fixed it"? If so, please delete the question.

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` statement doesn't actually execute the query, so it's impossible to obtain execution time from it, no matter the API. I'm not really sure what the question is about but I suspect you have a typo and haven't configured PDO to throw exceptions (by default it doesn't).

Comment: PHP5.6 is my current version.